# What are records in 'netstat' command are when using logstash?

Tags: netstat, elasticsearch, logstash

I use logstash with embedded elasticsearch. My logstash config looks like the following:

```
output {
  tdout { debug => true debug_format => "json"}

  elasticsearch {
    embedded => true
    cluster => "logs"
  }
}
```

When I issue command to see all opened ports by using

```
netstat -plunt
```

I get the following:
    [image]

What means :::* in the third column are? Does it mean that embedded elasticsearch opens 9200, 9300 and 9301 ports for listening from anywhere?

If so how could I restrict elasticsearch to listen only from localhost?

Comment: Does http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.5/outputs/elasticsearch help?

Comment: Unfortunately don't. I've tried to set bind_host and host to '127.0.0.1' but it seems there are igrored

Answer (score 1):

Hey it seems I get a trick and I've bound elasticsearch to my local machine but I had to write full machine IP instead just "127.0.0.1" or localhost. Also in the third column I still see

```
:::*
```

[image]

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

:::* you are right it listen from anywhere

To allow only to listen from localhost you can edit elasticsearch.yml file with next.

network.host: "127.0.0.1"
http.host: 127.0.0.1

You can also edit the iptables config and deny incoming  requests to the (9200-9300) elasticsearch ports

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have no elasticsearch.yml file because I installed logstash as java wrapper according by this http://spredzy.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/java-service-wrapper-or-how-to-daemonize-your-java-services-for-all-major-oses/

Comment: can you try with iptables

Comment: Can I create and point to this file somehow?

Comment: vladeli, but how could I use elasticsearch config in my case?

Comment: to be honest i never used elasticsearch as java wrapper so i dont have expirience in running like this, but try iptables it should work